# Split file to chunks: Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: python

My approach was this way:

```
def fChunks(l, n):
    """Chunks iterable into n sized chunks"""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
        
folder=r"_my_folder"
berkas_ori = pat(fr"{folder}\my_text.txt")

try:
    lines = []
    with open(berkas_ori,'r') as main_file:
#         head = [next(main_file) for x in range(1000)]
        total_baris = sum(1 for line in main_file)
        print(f"Total jlh baris: {total_baris:,.0f}")
        for line in main_file:
            lines.append(line)
        jlh_baris_chunk = math.ceil(total_baris/5)
        print(f"Jlh baris per chunk= {jlh_baris_chunk}")
        
    # Write each group of lines to separate files
    for i, group in enumerate(fChunks(lines, n=jlh_baris_chunk), start=1):
        berkas_tgt=pat(fr"{folder}\chunks\my_text_{i}.txt")
        with open(berkas_tgt, mode="w") as out_file:
            for line in group:
                out_file.write(line)
            print(f"Finish generating {berkas_tgt}")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

It is expected that a file of 3,137,672 lines will by splited to 5 chunks of file evenly.
No errors, but somehow it doesn't succeed as I expected. No files created.

What things i overlooked here?

Comment: ```berkas_ori = pat(fr"{folder}\my_text.txt")``` what is ```pat```?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur,
it is alias for Path: ```from pathlib import Path as pat```. 

I snip some lines of code to make it literally simpler.

Comment: Try printing ```lines```, I'm pretty sure it'll be an empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some trial, and add:
`with open(berkas_ori,'r') as main_file:` once again before
`for line in main_file:`

to be:

```
def fChunks(l, n):
    """Chunks iterable into n sized chunks"""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
        
folder=r"_my_folder"
berkas_ori = pat(fr"{folder}\my_text.txt")

try:
    lines = []
    with open(berkas_ori,'r') as main_file:
#         head = [next(main_file) for x in range(1000)]
        total_baris = sum(1 for line in main_file)
        print(f"Total jlh baris: {total_baris:,.0f}")
    with open(berkas_ori,'r') as main_file:
        for line in main_file:
            lines.append(line)
        jlh_baris_chunk = math.ceil(total_baris/5)
        print(f"Jlh baris per chunk= {jlh_baris_chunk}")
        
    # Write each group of lines to separate files
    for i, group in enumerate(fChunks(lines, n=jlh_baris_chunk), start=1):
        berkas_tgt=pat(fr"{folder}\chunks\my_text_{i}.txt")
        with open(berkas_tgt, mode="w") as out_file:
            for line in group:
                out_file.write(line)
            print(f"Finish generating {berkas_tgt}")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

It solved the problem, and 5 files created as expected.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the file cursor back to zero after the first iteration over file lines.

add

```
main_file.seek(0)
```

after

```
total_baris = sum(1 for line in main_file)
```

should do the job.